# Submit form and stay on same page?

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have a form that looks like this

```
<form action="receiver.pl" method="post">
  <input name="signed" type="checkbox">
  <input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

and I would like to stay on the same page, when Submit is clicked, but still have `receiver.pl` executed.

How should that be done?

Comment: simplest: add target="_blank" - less simple: ajax

Comment: So `receiver.pl` is opened in a new window/tab?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The easiest answer: jQuery. Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

If you want to add content dynamically and still need it to work, and also with more than one form, you can do this:

```
   $('form').live('submit', function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
```

Comment: This looks very interesting! How do I tell it to execute the `receiver.pl` script?

Comment: the part where it says '$form.attr('action')' does that - it tells jQuery's submit function to call the action specified by the form ('receiver.pl'), without leaving the page, i.e. using AJAX.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, because it still changes page to `receiver.pl` I have added your code to the header section, and included `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>`. Do I need to make other changes?

Comment: Btw. I have found this page, http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html , but I can't quite understand it.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had a mistake in my code - should have tested it. It's important to `return false;` at the end. Also, if the page returns an error in the javascript, the form will submit in the default way. That might be why it's still loading the new page.

Comment: Btw. It seams that this only works on the first form on the page. Can it be modified, so it works on all forms on the page?

Comment: This should work on all forms on the page - unless the forms are loaded after the rest of the page was loaded, which I presume it isn't.

Comment: I guess that's the problem then. I have written the page in Perl using `CGI::Application` and `HTML::Template`, where I only define one form, it is copied many times... Do you have an idea how that be worked around?

Comment: Well, that still shouldn't be a problem then - are you sure it doesn't work? Are the other forms valid? If you want, you could try replacing `$form.submit(function(){` with `$form.live('submit',function(){` but I doubt that will solve your problem. In all probability, it's related to something else. If you do that, you should also remove the first and last lines of my example code.

Comment: @Herman, your JQuery code looks like it's finding the first form on the page and altering how it is submited, you need to modify it to find all forms and loop through and modify them all.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: no, the code selects everything with a `form` tag, and then applies the `submit` function to each of the selected elements. Test it yourself on a selection for all <p> tags `$(p).css('background', '#f00');` - that will make all paragraphs have a red background, not just the first one.

Comment: @Herman. If I make that change, then it doesn't stay on the same page. Here is the HTML template, where I have pasted your code in. http://pastebin.com/ERMqkPVF

Comment: @Sandra: It doesn't reload the page when I click save, seems to work with me - something else might be causing a javascript error, and that might cause the page to reload.

Comment: That is correct with the version of your code from the accepted answer, but making the `$form.live('submit',function(){` change does.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer just to make sure we're understanding each other correctly.

Comment: Damn! You are good! Now it works for all forms =) So the problem was that, JavaScript is executed before `HTML::Template` is done render the HTML?

Comment: No, both code snippets in my answer should work in your case (as far as I know) - it might just have been something small - I don't know why it didn't work in the first place. But I'm glad if it works now :)

Comment: Me too =) I got to find a good JQuery book, and learn this awesome library! http://www.learningjquery.com/ seams popular.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there, I learnt all I know from the jQuery documentation ;) but take a look at this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/q/96818/445210 - seems most people recommend jQuery in Action

Comment: JQuery in Action is cheaper. I think we have a winner =)

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunately if you use a button inside your form its value will not be sent along..:(

Comment: Do you know if this will submit multipart forms correctly? I have a feeling it won't but could someone confirm?

Comment: @Josh No, but you can see how to do it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) and also [here](http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax).

Comment: will it handle multi type form datas? i mean,will it work on input type file submit?

Comment: @Kvvaradha No, to handle file uploads you will need to send that explicitly with jquery's `data` parameter to the `$.ajax` function, `new FormData($(this)[0]);` and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/445210

Answer (score 91):

99% of the time I would use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for something like this. However, there's an alternative solution which doesn't require javascript...

You could include a hidden iframe on your page and set the target attribute of your form to point to that iframe.

```
<style>
  .hide { position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px; width:1px; height:1px; }
</style>

<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>

<form action="receiver.pl" method="post" target="hiddenFrame">
  <input name="signed" type="checkbox">
  <input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

There are very few scenarios where I would choose this route. Generally handling it with javascript is better because, with javascript you can...

- gracefully handle errors (e.g. retry)
- provide UI indicators (e.g. loading, processing, success, failure)
- run logic before the request is sent, or run logic after the response is received.

Comment: Didn't say that this was the best answer out there. Just another option. ;)

Comment: This actually may be the best answer here... You don't have to use Jquery, Ajax etc

Comment: I am also struck in a similar situation and tried what @jessegavin suggested. But upon submission the perl cgi is not fetching the form elements. Any suggestions?

Comment: Btwn - the fields/form elements are being populated by jQuery datepicker

Comment: @GovindKailas Maybe you should post your own StackOverflow question because it's probably not directly related to this one.  However, double check that all your fields have a `name` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I just got one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319469/jquery-elements-not-getting-passed-to-perl-cgi
@jessegavin

Comment: I like this one because it is the most simple, doesnt require additional libraries and just uses html.  I was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 45):

The HTTP/CGI way to do this would be for your program to return an HTTP status code of 204 (No Content).

Comment: Super cool! Learned something new today. 

Howerver, in practical terms, you would really want to provide the user with some sort of visual feedback that the form submission was processed by the server. It doesn't seem that browsers provide that out of the box, so using AJAX to interpret the HTTP 204 would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Wow... Thanks!... This is really an amazing tip, It doesn't exactly 100% solve the problem I'm having but it's definitely an temporary solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: A simple and great way of doing it in simple html.  Great!

Comment: That is such a nice way to do it. Much simpler than other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit on the submit button, the page is sent to the server. 
If you want to send it async, you can do it with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
}
xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
// xhr.send(new Int8Array()); 
// xhr.send(document);
```