# How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple form with remote=true.

This form is actually on an HTML Dialog, which gets closed as soon as the Submit button is clicked.

Now I need to make some changes on the main HTML page after the form gets submitted successfully.

I tried this using jQuery. But this doesn't ensure that the tasks get performed after some form of response of the form submission.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {

// do the task here ..

});
```

How do I attach a callback, so that my code gets executed only after the form is successfully submitted? Is there any way to add some .success or .complete callback to the form?

Comment: Why dont you use Ajax? With jQuery Ajax functions you can define such callbacks.

Comment: davidbuzatto, there are some cases when you cannot use ajax. For instance, when you want to upload a file.

Comment: @Pere Not true here in the future.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I just did this -

```
 $("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {

         // tasks to do 


   });
```

And things worked perfectly .

See [this api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) for more specific details.

Comment: Wow... I just learned something new. Yeah, from the looks of it, this is the most simplest solution. Perhaps, it's even the best. I am an avid Coding Horror reader, and in that blog, Jeff Attwood emphasizes that we should write less code, and this method achieves that. Good find. :)

Comment: Please tell me how could you use ajax:complete when binding your form? we can't find any property related to a form like 'ajax:complete'.

Comment: Ajax:complete can be attached to any Ajax Event . When the event completes , this is triggered . In my form I used "remote=true" - which means the form gets submitted via Ajax . So u can attach a ajax:complete to the form submissionhttp://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: And if the `<form>` is submited usually ? (I mean not with Ajax) What can I put in the first argument of `.bind()` ? EDIT : well, I guess `click`. Nvm, sorry. :p

Comment: beware: this is going to fire your function after the completion of **any** ajax event, not just your form submission (unless I'm mistaken, in which case I'd love for you to provide a link for where you found this)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the form is created dynamically, like in the following:
`var form = $("<form>", {'action': 'somepath.html','method':'post'}).bind('ajax:complete', function() {console.log("AJAX COMPLETE");});`

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document"

Comment: Where is 'ajax:complete' defined?  In the jQuery docs, it's "ajaxComplete".  http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: Didn´t work form me, using normal Form, with a button, but the button calls javascript $('#formFile').submit();

Comment: Also it didn't work for me. I've created dynamic form, and triggered submit, but after, when I've got the answer from ajax, listener with ajax:complete does't triggered.

Comment: @JamaicaGeek - thank you - do you know how i can succeed binding to a dynamically generated form?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - This wont work for a dynamically generated form as it is. You will need to use something like http://api.jquery.com/live/ or http://api.jquery.com/on/ to cater to dynamic elements.

Comment: If this isn't working for you, such as in the case of dynamically generated form the solution should be to bind the listener to the document instead like this: `$(document).bind('ajax:complete', "#my-form", function() { this.doesFoo(); });

Comment: got curious how this got that much upvotes, as it doesn't apply to normal forms (sent with a submit button). The answer by Bradley is more complete and explains how this one could "work" (if you didn't include a success callback, what makes no sense at all).

Answer (score 41):

I could not get the number one upvoted solution to work reliably, but have found this works.  Not sure if it's required or not, but I do not have an action or method attribute on the  tag, which ensures the POST is handled by the $.ajax function and gives you the callback option.

```
<form id="form">
...
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_selector").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "form_handler.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        // callback code here
       }
    })

  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: +1. The key to this answer is the `$(this).serialize()` line. It lets you use `jQuery.ajax()` to submit the existing form in the background, then catch the reply from the server and do something with it.

Comment: javascript without semicolons... some people just want to watch the world burn. Your solution works though, so thanks :)

Comment: Note that `.serialize` doesn't include file inputs in your POSTed request. Use the HTML5 FormData (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10899384/957950)) instead unless you are supporting old browsers like IE < 9

Comment: Props for using `$(this).serialize()`, it solved my problems!

Comment: what is 'form_selector' in your html that you reference in the js?

Comment: @KevinMeredith it's the id of the form... Same thing as "#myform" in the original posting.

Comment: Actually [Eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-semi) suggest to not use unnecessary semicolons, and it won't burn the world :) @viggity. The solution works perfectly for me, thanks.

Comment: @wenwen That lint rule is for *extra* semi-colon. It does not discourage the use of them, it just says don't use two when one is enough. I for one agree with viggity, not using them will make the world burn, or at least your code when someone accidentally removes a line break.

Comment: I added this code to a form on my website. However, now the side is reloading on click of the button. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 24):

You'll have to do things manually with an AJAX call to the server. This will require you to override the form as well.

But don't worry, it's a piece of cake. Here's an overview on how you'll go about working with your form:

- override the default submit action (thanks to the passed in event object, that has a `preventDefault` method)
- grab all necessary values from the form
- fire off an HTTP request
- handle the response to the request

First, you'll have to cancel the form submit action like so:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    // Cancels the form's submit action.
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And then, grab the value of the data. Let's just assume you have one text box.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
});
```

And then fire off a request. Let's just assume it's a POST request.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();

    // I like to use defers :)
    deferred = $.post("http://somewhere.com", { val: val });

    deferred.success(function () {
        // Do your stuff.
    });

    deferred.error(function () {
        // Handle any errors here.
    });
});
```

And this should about do it.

**Note 2:** For parsing the form's data, it's preferable that you use a [plugin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/). It will make your life really easy, as well as provide a nice semantic that mimics an actual form submit action.

**Note 2:** You don't have to use defers. It's  just a personal preference. You can equally do the following, and it should work, too.

```
$.post("http://somewhere.com", { val: val }, function () {
    // Start partying here.
}, function () {
    // Handle the bad news here.
});
```

Comment: Great sample. How to do the same thing with file upload (multi-part/form-data) ???

Comment: Note 2: Don't use a plugin for handling form data, or manually grab each value from the form yourself. 
Use the JS FormData object to take the entire form's data all at once, including multi-part/file data: 
`var formData = new FormData(this);`

Answer (score 10):

For MVC here was an even easier approach.
You need to use the Ajax form and set the AjaxOptions

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadTrainingMedia", "CreateTest", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "displayUploadMediaMsg" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmUploadTrainingMedia" }))
{ 
  ... html for form
}
```

here is the submission code, this is in the document ready section and ties the onclick event of the button to to submit the form

```
$("#btnSubmitFileUpload").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#frmUploadTrainingMedia").submit();
});
```

here is the callback referenced in the AjaxOptions

```
function displayUploadMediaMsg(d){
    var rslt = $.parseJSON(d.responseText);
    if (rslt.statusCode == 200){
        $().toastmessage("showSuccessToast", rslt.status);
    }
    else{
        $().toastmessage("showErrorToast", rslt.status);
    }
}
```

in the controller method for MVC it looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult UploadTrainingMedia(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // there is only one file  ... do something with it
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            statusCode = 200,
            status = "File uploaded",
            file = "",
        }, "text/html");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            statusCode = 400,
            status = "Unable to upload file",
            file = "",
        }, "text/html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Those code are .Net codes, and in the question never specified it.

Comment: That really isn't a good reason for down voting this.  The answer works and might help a .NET developer who is facing the same issue.

Comment: I like this idea, but for some reason the callback isn't firing.  Does the controller method have to return a JsonResult?  My controller method currently returns an ActionResult.

Answer (score 7):

I do not believe there is a callback-function like the one you describe.

What is normal here is to do the alterations using some server-side language, like PHP.

In PHP you could for instance fetch a hidden field from your form and do some changes if it is  present.

PHP:

```
  $someHiddenVar = $_POST["hidden_field"];
    if (!empty($someHiddenVar)) {
        // do something 
    }
```

One way to go about it in Jquery is to use Ajax. You could listen to submit, return false to cancel its default behaviour and use jQuery.post() instead. jQuery.post has a success-callback.

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize(), function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

The form's "on submit" handlers are called before the form is submitted.  I don't know if there is a handler to be called after the form is submited.  In the traditional non-Javascript sense the form submission will reload the page.

Comment: Unless the form submission redirects to a file download, in which case the page is left intact. I can't use JavaScript submission because an Ajax request can't initiate a file download (without anchor tag games), but I also can't tell the user to wait, or clean up once they have the file...

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#formid").ajaxForm({ success: function(){ //to do after submit } });
```

Comment: Is `ajaxForm()` a third-party component you have installed? It is not a standard part of jQuery.