# Detect actual form submit and show loader

Tags: javascript, jquery-validation-engine

I have a form which has jQuery-Validation-Engine enabled and I want to show a loader once the form is actually getting submitted i.e. when it is without errors. If I am using following code, its getting called even when there are errors in form.

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(){
  showLoaderGIF here;
});
```

I would like to know how to detect the actual form submit and not just click on submit button ? Is there any way I can use jQuery-Validation-Engine's 'onSuccess' callback ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve this using following code

```
$("my-form").validationEngine('attach', {    
  onValidationComplete: function(form,status){
    if(status == true){
      showLoader;
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch the `$("#my-form").submit`, write a couple of functions to show/hide my loader image, and use the following hooks:

```
jQuery("#my-form").validationEngine({
  ...
  onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: showLoader,
  onAjaxFormComplete: hideLoader,
  ...
});
```

**Edit**

Ok, so to display if the form is valid but **not** allow it to submit, you could use the [onValidationComplete](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#options/onvalidationcomplete) option:

```
jQuery("#my-form").validationEngine('attach', {
  onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
    if(status) { showLoader(); }
  }  
});
```

Comment: in my case the form is not yet submitted to server. I want to show loader if (form is error free && submit button is clicked)