# Hide form submit button with jQuery only when for actually submits

Tags: jquery, forms

For a while I have been using the following code...

```
$("input[type=submit]:not(.noHide)").one('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).click(function () { return false; });
});
```

to disable form submit buttons on click, primarily to avoid double clicks submitting twice.

I now have a form or two with required fields...

```
<input type="date" name="DatePurchased" required>
```

and this kind of breaks since the submit button is now gone once the omission is corrected.

Is there a way to disable the button only after a successful submission and not just a click?

Comment: check for validation errors before hiding/disabling it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit

Comment: yet another side effect of using the wrong event handler for form submit handling.

Answer (score 1):

Use the submit-event instead.

```
$("input[type=submit]:not(.noHide)").on('submit', function() {
    if ($(this).not(':visible')) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be hiding the button at all.

Comment: It seems the submit event can only be attached to forms, not the submit button.