# How can I refresh a datatable on rails after an update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm a Rails newbie and I have a full working datatable (thanks to [railscasts #340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables)).

In my datatable view I set up 2 buttons:

```
<button id="Refresh" type="button">Refresh</button>
<td><%= button_to 'dogroup', dogroup_utyord_path(format: "json"), remote: true %></td>

<table id="utyords" class="display" data-source="<%= utyords_url(format: "json") %>" width="100%">
...
</table>
```

Here is my working coffescript:

```
jQuery ->
  oUtyordTable = $('#utyords').dataTable
  sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
  bJQueryUI: true
  bProcessing: true
  bServerSide: true
  sAjaxSource: $('#utyords').data('source')

$("#Refresh").click ->
  oUtyordTable.fnDraw()
```

in my controller:

```
def index
  @utyords = Utyord.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: UtyordsDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end

def dogroup
  ddett = Utyord.all
  ddett.update_all "grp = 1"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json 
  end
end
```

I push the "dogroup" button and the action updates records on the database correctly: when I push the "refresh" button I can see the datatable updated.

Everything works fine, but.... is there a way the datatable updates when I push the "dogroup" button without have to push the "refresh" button?

I know I miss something...

Answer (score 0):

Could something as simple as this work?

```
$('input[value="dogroup"]').mouseup ->
    oUtyordTable.fnDraw()
```

Try it... Mouseup because we want it to run after click.

If it doesn't, then add an identifier to the form:

```
<%= button_to 'dogroup', dogroup_utyord_path(format: "json"), 
                         remote: true, form_class: "dogroup_form" %>
```

And then submit the form and after than run a script:

```
$(".dogroup_form").submit(e)->
     e.preventDefault()         #to stop the form
     $(this).submit()           #to manually submit it and
     oUtyordTable.fnDraw()      #to run your function
```

**UPDATE**: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit) post: to use a response from a form's ajax request that has not been handled by your own code, you can bind an event to your form (in plain `javascript`, not `coffeescript`):

Discard my proposed `$(".dogroup_form").submit(e)->` functionality and add this:

```
$(".dogroup_form").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
    oUtyordTable.fnDraw();
});
```

From [online](http://js2coffee.org/), this could be the `CoffeeScript` equivalent to the above:

```
$(".dogroup_form").bind "ajax:complete", ->
    oUtyordTable.fnDraw()
    return
```

Comment: Hi Ruby Racer, thanks so much for your reply. I tried your suggestion but it works only after the second push on the button. It happens in either way (first and second solution). I thought there is something in

Comment: I thought there is maybe something in 
    respond_to do |format|
that I don't understand...

Comment: Ok. Check my updated answer, from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit