# Ruby on rails Datatables refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datatables

I try to update the Datatables when you click the button.
My JQuery code in "spr_well_types.js.coffee":

```
jQuery ->  
   sprWellTable = $('#spr_well_types').dataTable
      sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
      bJQueryUI: true
      bProcessing: true
      bServerSide: true
      sAjaxSource: $('#spr_well_types').data('source')

$(document).ready ->
  $("#Refresh").on "click", (event) ->
    sprWellTable.fnDraw()
```

My page "index.html.erb":

```
<button id="Refresh" type="button">Refresh</button>
<table id="spr_well_types" class="display" data-source="<%= spr_well_types_url(format: "json")%>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Short Name</th>
      <th>Lock version</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Code I click on the Refresh button in the browser error "ReferenceError: sprWellTable is not defined".
I saw the [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515390/how-can-i-refresh-a-datatable-on-rails-after-an-update-action), but the code:

```
$("#Refresh").click ->
  sprWellTable.fnDraw()
```

Not tied to the Refresh button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#Refresh").on "click", (event) ->
    $("#spr_well_types").dataTable().fnDraw()
```