# Call function after ajax load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I initiate a function after an ajax load(), but the function I intimate calls upon an additional function, which isn't working. How do I initiate `ajaxstuff()` after `load()`?

```
function ajaxstuff(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "do-it.php",
        data: {data},
        success: function() {
            console.log('I got this far'); // this doesn't work / isn't called
        }
    });
}

function doit() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        console.log('I got this far'); // this works
        ajaxstuff(formData);
    }
}

$('.popup-loader').click(function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="popup"></div>');
    $('.popup').load('popup.php', function() {
        doit(); // this works
    }
});
```

Comment: in ajaxstuff method, I see only the success callback. Try adding the  
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
            } to see if you are getting any error.

Comment: Also, I see that you are sending FormData to ajax post. Set, data: data,
        processData: false.

Comment: maybe start by reading the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
there is no "load" scenario with ajax, you have success, fail, and always

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit)

Comment: Try removing the curly brackets from `data` whithin your Ajax call

Answer (score -2):

Syntax error in `ajaxstuff` function. `data: {data},` , probably should be `data: data,`

Also when you're passing a FormData object to $.ajax, you have to specify `processData: false` and `contentType: false`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "do-it.php",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log('I got this far'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Check for errors in your console, also, in your AJAX add an `async` option. set it to FALSE ("Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called"):

```
function ajaxstuff(data) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "do-it.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
             console.log(result); //check in your console for errors
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This would have nothing to do with the `success` block not firing - and it's true by default.

Comment: `async: false` is depracated as of jQuery 1.8 and he's already using the success callback.