# callback when form submitted using submit() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, submit

I have read following SO [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11534690/2674303)

and I have wrote following code:

```
$form = $("#form"); 
$form.bind('ajax:complete', function() {
            alert("done");
 });
 $form.submit();
```

But I don't see alert after submit click.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zh8um27/1/)

Fiddle a bit wrong because I don't know endpoint where I can send request. but on my local mashine I see same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach handler in you form's onsubmit event first, then inside that handler call ajax, when ajax is successful the display message done:

```
   $form = $("#form"); 
    $form.on("submit",function()
    {
       alert("submitting..");
       //do ajax
       $.ajax({
                 url:<submit url>,
                 type:post/get,
                 success:function() { alert("done");  }
             });
    });
     $form.submit();
```

Please read more about DOM event handling and ajax using JQuery/Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.8 changed this nature, from that version onwards the ajaxComplete and other global handlers can be attached to the document object only

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

[ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9dy5xL8q/)

Comment: Is there event beforeSend?

Comment: @gstackoverflow http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ - you have http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Comment: I need exactly **$form.submit();** because after form submit I download file