# How can I refresh a page after form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

Hi can anyone help me on this issue, please post whole code because i am really a noob in coding and allready lost many hours searching for the right answer. If i want to vote for this game see "spielbewertung" on this page
**http://www.spielonline.ch/spiel.php/Kogama-Ostry.html**
the page loads the iframe nickolodeonspelheader.php from the page spiel.php after voting and the url looks like this
http://www.spielonline.ch/**nickelodeonspelheader.php**/Kogama-Ostry.html which offcourse is wrong it should change the data in the database after input and come back on the original parent page so the game can be played after voting. This is the form code:

```
<table style="display: inline-block;"><tr>

<td class="top" colspan="1" width="100%"><h2>Spielbewertung</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="50%" style="align:left;">
    <form name="rating" action="" method="post">
      <p style="font-family: tahoma; font-size: x-small;">
        <b>Spiel bewerten:</b>
                     <select name="number">
                      <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="3">3 = sehr schlecht</option>
        <option value="4">4 = mangelhaft</option> 
        <option value="5">5 = langweilig</option>
        <option value="6">6 = ausreichend</option>
        <option value="7">7 = befriedigend</option>
        <option value="8">8 = gut</option>
        <option value="9">9 = sehr gut</option>
        <option value="10">10 = hervorragend</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="vote" value="bewerten" style="cursor: pointer" />        
                              </p>
                 </form>

    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Many thanks for help in advance!

Comment: a redirect keeps loading the page over and over again or i must done something wrong, give me the right redirect code if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use suggestion from this post: [callback when form submitted using submit() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113939/callback-when-form-submitted-using-submit-method)
And replace alert("done") with location.reload();

For example:

```
<!-- Import jQuery in your <head> tag -->

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- your html source -->

<table style="display: inline-block;"><tr>

<td class="top" colspan="1" width="100%"><h2>Spielbewertung</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="50%" style="align:left;">

<!-- Add id attribute for form -->

    <form id="submit-form" name="rating" action="" method="post">
  <p style="font-family: tahoma; font-size: x-small;">
    <b>Spiel bewerten:</b>
                 <select name="number">
                  <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="3">3 = sehr schlecht</option>
    <option value="4">4 = mangelhaft</option> 
    <option value="5">5 = langweilig</option>
    <option value="6">6 = ausreichend</option>
    <option value="7">7 = befriedigend</option>
    <option value="8">8 = gut</option>
    <option value="9">9 = sehr gut</option>
    <option value="10">10 = hervorragend</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="bewerten" style="cursor: pointer" />        
                          </p>
             </form>

</td></tr>
```

```
<script>
$form = $("#submit-form"); 
$form.on("submit",function()
{
   alert("submitting..");
   //do ajax
   $.ajax({
       url:<submit url>,
       type:post,
       success:function() {
           location.reload();
       }
   });
});
$form.submit();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please i dont understand the code there and need to know exactly what i need to put in my page to make it work.

Comment: `location.reload()` refreshes the page. You just need to call that when the form is submitted. Here he is submitting the form asynchronously and then when that is complete, refreshing the page.

Comment: Where do i put that ajax script just after the input line or after </form> ? Do i need to fill in something in that script or does it work just like that?

Comment: @JacobVendrig please have a look at http://jquery.org and the js docs of the mozilla developer network

Comment: @linherest: if you use jquery, please at least tell it, or include the necessary files...

Comment: That script does not change anything it keeps loading nickelodeonspelheader.php instead of spiel.php after voting

Comment: i put it after </form>

Comment: Hi @Linherest, You need this to fix it ? this is my starting code on the nickelodeonspelheader.php page:

Comment: First part: <?php
ob_start();
$pad = ''; // slash als laatste teken
// Alternatieve _GET var opbouwen
if(!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
{
   $_aGET = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
   $_aGET = explode('/', $_aGET);
}
if(file_exists($pad . $_aGET[0] . '.php')){
   include $pad . $_aGET[0] . '.php';
}else{
  $string1 = $_aGET[0];
  $spel = str_replace("-", " ", $string1);
  $spel = str_replace(".html", "", $spel);
}
include_once "config.php";

Comment: Last part of the starting code:

Comment: $select = ("SELECT * FROM ". $pre ."$sqlgame WHERE name = '$spel'"); // Selecteren uit een tabel
$query = mysql_query($select); 
$list = mysql_fetch_object($query);

mysql_query ("UPDATE ". $pre ."$sqlgame SET views=views+1 where name = '$spel'");
///

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

Comment: The spiel.php starts with the same code

Comment: Any suggestions ?????

Comment: Guess i need to pay again for an expert in this matter, i keep paying thanks anyway.