# Hoisting causing issues in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am declaring the global variable `isValid` to `true` initially. Then when I navigate across tabs, I submit the form and upon submit, the value of `isValid` is changed to `false`. However, the first time I navigate, it alerts a value of `true` rather than `false`. For some reason, the submit function is being invoked after the alert statement. What can I do so that it is invoked before the alert statement?

```
var isValid = true;

$('form').on('submit', function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code
    isValid = false;
}

$(document).on('hide.bs.tab', '.nav-pills a', function()) {
    $('form').submit();
    alert(isValid);
}
```

Comment: Form submission typically causes a redirect, unless you have an `e.preventDefault()` hidden inside of `// rest of the code`...

Comment: Yes, `e.preventDefault()` is hidden inside the `rest of the code` but I edited the code to show it now.

Answer (score 2):

The submit handler is getting called asynchronously, so the order may be non-deterministic. You could put the alert call in your handler, or consider using something like jQuery deferred.promise() to control the flow of calls.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How would you ensure that the ajax request is completed, before any jquery is executed?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit