# How to reload the google recaptcha after submit button without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, recaptcha, captcha

I'm looking a JavaScript code to reload google recaptcha after submit button without refreshing page.

Actually this following code is working, but once I click on submit button, it won't allow my form to submit, the recaptcha will be reset. I'm looking for a solution that after submit button, then recaptcha will be unchecked without effecting to my form. Because my form response is in the same page, that's why I want to reset recaptcha after form submitted.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
grecaptcha.reset();     
});
```

I highly appreciate if you will help me on this.

Comment: You cannot use the handler on [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) because that is called before it actually goes through.  You will need to either use some form of `$.ajax` or the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086670/3072752)

Comment: Thanks for your guide and help. I could solve it. thumbs up

Answer (score 4):

Special Thanks to user: [Sven The Surfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072752/sven-the-surfer)

Here is my Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form_captcha").submit(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
success: function() {
grecaptcha.reset();     
}})})})
```

Above Ajax need jquery.min.js version 3.2.1