# Call a function when submit finish

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function when submit finish. The submit open a pdf in a new tab.

```
$(form).submit() // fire the submit
```

but when I tried this approch

```
$(form).submit(function(e){            
        callfunction();
    }
);
```

The submit doesn't fire.

Here is my code.

```
<form id="form" action="#" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="docId">            
</form>

function getSubmitAttribute(data) {
    $form = $("#form");
    $(form).find("input[name=docId]").val($(data).parent().attr('id'));
    return form;
}

$('#datable tbody').on('click', '.cell', function () {
    form = getSubmitAttribute($(this));
    $(form).attr('action', url);
    $(form).submit();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit)

Comment: Suggsting to use stack overflow snippet https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @TusharAcharekar: Snippets don't allow form submission, not even when the target is set to open a new window. Sadly.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen No :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this in projects is to have the response containing the PDF set a cookie (since I can't have it run code, it's not a web page). Then I can poll for the cookie in the page sending the form. In pseudo-code:

```
$(form).submit();
var timeout = Date.now() + TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS;
poll();
function poll() {
    if (theCookieValueExists()) {
        // Done
    } else if (Date.now() > timeout) {
        // Give up
    } else {
        // Keep waiting
        setTimeout(poll, POLL_INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

I send the cookie name and value with the form, ensuring that they're *(very likely to be)* unique, so that if this is happening in multiple windows the code doesn't get confused.

Comment: Thank you but I think that I can not read a cookie with jquery created by php (Symfony)

Comment: @Mercenaire: I'm afraid you're incorrect there. :-) You can indeed use PHP to create a cookie, which can then be read by your JavaScript code (jQuery doesn't help you read cookies, though [there's a plugin for it that does](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)).

Comment: I think JavaScript too ? I'm going to search how

Comment: @Mercenaire: JavaScript code on the browser can read cookies set by PHP once the response from PHP has been received by the browser. (Unless you go out of your way to prevent it, by making the cookie "HTTP only".)

Comment: I receive it well in my chrome browser, it only remains to know how to read it in javascript

Comment: @Mercenaire: Good good. The subject of how to read cookies is **well** covered on the 'net. (Or you could use the plugin referenced above.)

Comment: @Mercenaire: Nice one!