# Ajax File Upload plugin

Tags: php, ajax

I am searching complete example with code for [Really simple jQuery Ajax File Upload plugin](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html)
but after visiting Download links there is no complete code with example. Pls guide from where I could get ..

Comment: Thanks but this helped me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score 1):

may be below links will help.

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html

http://www.saaraan.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I used [this Ajax uploader](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to upload form content with file attachments

Answer (score 0):

take a look at blueimp [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

very simple and available on github

Comment: Thanks
but it is not as per my requirements. If u check my url it is a form with different fields + file. that is what i need.