# How to serialize form with file inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax submit to post values to my php file along with some file inputs in it. It is not serializing my file and i found out that jquery only does this for form elements excluding file inputs. Can anyone please help me do this.

Comment: You can do it with HTML+ PHP + jQuery as mentioned here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score -1):

You can't submit file data with the basic jQuery ajax function.

I suggest using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) which works really well with ajax uploads and is easy to implement.

**Edit:** You can upload files via ajax using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface, however it is not supported by IE lower than 10. I still recommend using the plugin mentioned above.