# File upload through AJAX call, it's possible or not? I'm confused

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm working on an application where I'm sending data from a form by serializing it and then sending it through AJAX. Everything works perfect but I've got the first headache is that when the form has a field of type `FILE` for upload any kind of file (should be restricted to images only but this is another topic) to my server-side (Symfony2 controller action) code does not get the image field and therefore can not perform any action on the same.

I've done some research ([1](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax),[4](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/) and many more docs found at Google) and in some cases it is said that it's possible and in some instance says it is not, others use the `XHR object` and then I'm confused and not know where to go from here, here I leave my code to throw him a look and tell me what's wrong and what should I do to make the upload if possible (I think it's):

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: '{{ path('update-product', {'id': id}) }}',
    data: $('.smart-form').serializeArray(),
    success: function (data) {
        // here goes a message if all was fine
    }
});
```

This is the HTML field:

```
<input type="file" id="product_imageFile_file" name="product[imageFile][file]" class="valid">
```

Of course my form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and this is the request I got from Symfony2 controller action:

```
array(4)
   [product_name]: string (10) "Producto-1"
   [active]: string (1) "1"
   [product_description]: string (21) "DescripcionProducto-1"
   [_token]: string (43) "sjcpVT34_9-V7Z2doTZsvZsAewO-0Q5hD-a9C6VPNc4"
```

And as can see here there is not `product[imageFile][file]` on the request so something is wrong in my jQuery code, can any give me some help or point me to the right place?

**NOTE:** Since I'm using PHP and some of it's bundles to handle file upload and then manage the entities I don't know if will be a good practice to use any of the thousands of jQuery plugins to do that, that's the cause I don't mention here and I don't use them at all

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it's possible but you won't see the file the way you're doing it. Google *dropzone ajax upload*. That plugin works fine for me.

Comment: Plenty of jQuery plugins that do just that.

Comment: @Popnoodles take a look to the note I leave at main post the same for Lee Taylor

Comment: @ReynierPM I don't understand that sentence. To reiterate, **you won't find the file in the ajax-posted form data**. Pick a plugin and read the instructions fully.

Comment: @Popnoodles I'm saying that I'm using [this bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md) that handle all the upload and entities managment as Symfony2 does, but if you said that it's possible thorugh a plugin then I'll read the docs

Comment: The bundle looks like it only handles the uploads server-side. You know the simplest way to do it, if you don't want a progress bar, is to post to a hidden iframe.

Comment: @Popnoodles no, I don't need a progress bar or something I just need that the file is send through AJAX that's what I ask in first and I don't follow you with your latest comment around hidden iframe, could you leave a example? If is possible with some test code?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online, there's no need for another. Posting to an iframe is not sending via ajax, it just means the page doesn't need reloading.

Comment: use FormData() with ajax to give PHP it's usual $_FILES, or catch the POST data and handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally and after a lot of research I get it and without any external library as some users suggest here, maybe it's a ugly method but it works for me and does what I want. Here is the code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            // Display some alert or show the user the file is wrong
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img id="product_image" class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('pImage').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('imageFile_file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url, // the URL for process the whole form
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#formID').serialize() + '&img=' + JSON.stringify($("#product_image").attr('src')),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data)
    {
        if (typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Handle success here
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
    },
    complete: function ()
    {
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
```

Hope helps someone else