# Unable send data to php file via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my HTML code.I'm not using `<form>`

```
<input id="sortpicture" type="file" data-id="7" name="sortpic" multiple/>
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

Here is JS

```
jQuery('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = jQuery('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];       
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data); 
    form_data.append('id', 7); // ---> If I send this only i'm able to access `id` in php. If include `file` not access id in php file.

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',   
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){        
        },
        error:function(e){
        }
    });
```

PHP file

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
//print_r($_FILES);
$id = $_POST['id'];    // Unable to get id.
```

How can I get `id` in php file.Any suggestions please.

Comment: Have you looked at [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: Your snippet should be working.. Kindly check your param headers in your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation, I believe you're close. Keep in mind that I have never used the FormData API :) But, if I am interpreting it correctly, it's looking for the "name" attribute.

```
jQuery('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    var inputData = $('this').find('input');
    var fileData = inputData.files[0];       

    formData.append('file', fileData); //wants name attribute here?//
    formData.append('id', 7);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',   
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,                         
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){        
        },
        error:function(e){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `form_data.append('sortpic', file); //wants name attribute here?//` — That would be `'sortpic'`. The code in the question uses `'file'` which is the name that code tries to read from in PHP. It doesn't matter what the field was called in the DOM, the data set is being constructed manually.

Comment: It matters on the client side. Obviously if you are using the wrong selector the javascript is not going to work. I understand PHP sees it as ['file'], didn't dispute that.

Comment: The first argument of `append` is not a selector, its the name you are assigning the value (the second argument) to.

Comment: `input` is undefined, so that will throw an exception