# Making ajax driven form with file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, http-post

How can I easily implement "formData" in this ajax call?

HTML:

```
<form id="insertDocument" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <select name="type_d" id="type_d">
        <option value="1">something</option>
        <option value="2">something</option>
        <option value="3">something</option>
        <option value="3">something</option>
        <option value="3">something</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="description_d">
    <input type="date" name="date_d">
    <input type="date" name="valid_d">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload document" id="insert_d">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#insert_d").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#insertDocument").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insertDocument.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is, that I need to post all the data - file and other inputs. Do I have to combine formData with serialize?

Comment: I need an example of implementing this particular solution in my case. Maybe the content is duplicate, but solution is not.

Comment: May this link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax