# Send input files data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**html markup:**

```html
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```

I am uploading multiples files with php. I want to make an array of upload files and send to server with ajax. how to make an array of the multiple selected files?

**JavaScript:**

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'insertfiles.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      file: // array of selected files.
    },
    success: function(data){
    },
    error: function(data){
      alert( 'Sorry.' );
    }
});
```

Comment: The only way to send files with ajax is with `FormData`, see [***THIS***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously#answer-8758614)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modern browsers that support the **HTML5** file stuff have in the `<input>` element a "files" property.
That will give you a file list reference, which has a `length` property.

As the property is already an `array` so you just need to access it or iterate through it.

**JS**

```
var input = document.getElementById('id');
console.log(input.files);

for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
 console.log(input.files[i]);
}
```

Comment: alert( input.files[i] ) giving me object. is it right?

Comment: @HassanAli yes is correct, it is an array of File objects, each file has properties like name, type and size. Try alert( input.files[i].name);

Comment: one question do i send array using input.files[i].name or input.files[i]?

Answer (score 12):

Use the code below.

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formid")[0]);
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'insertfiles.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  success: function(data) {
        
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert( 'Sorry.' );
  },
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This will send both text and files

Comment: [object FormData] how to check the data in alert()?

Comment: could you please explain `var formData = new FormData($("#formid")[0]);`

Comment: @KanishkaBKodithuwakku Just have a look at this documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Great! Worked for me. Keep in mind -data- in success call back must be JSON parsed in order to access its goodies: `var myobj = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: You must also add `processData: false, contentType: false,` to the jQuery.ajax call, otherwise Jquery will try to transform formData into string, and there will be "Illegal invocation" error.

Answer (score 4):

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
debugger;
$.ajax({
  url: formURL,
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    debugger;
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    
  }
});
```

The above code will help you post content plus files in one submit call.

The post method parameter should include `HttpPostedFileBase[] file` so the list of files will appear in this file parameter

Answer (score -14):

This is my code for multiple file upload.
Please refer this

```
$fileCount = count($_FILES);
for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
$fileName = (!empty($_FILES["file-$i"]["name"])) ? $_FILES["file-$i"]["name"] : '';

$hostName = "REDACTED";
$userName = "REDACTED";
$passWord = "REDACTED";
$dbName   = "b7_15386696_db_printer";

$query    = "INSERT INTO print_table (NAME, EMAIL, PHONE, ADDRESS, FILENAME, NUMBEROFCOPY, SREQUIREMENTS, FIELD1)
VALUES ('$name', '$emailId', '$phone', '$address', '$fileName', '$ncopy', '$requirements', CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+09:30'))";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostName,"$userName","$passWord","$dbName");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: Are you aware you put in database credentials?