# Data and files in one ajax - How to process post sended by JS FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

i`m struggling with one problem. I used example from this thread

[Data and files in one ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

I used this example

```
$("form#data").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});

return false; 

});
```

My example looks like this:

**HTML Form + Ajax send**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo" id="fm" action="">
    <label>Your email address:</label>
    <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />
    <label>Custom file label:</label>
    <input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" /><br />
    <label>File to stash:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>



<script>
    $('#fm').on('submit', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
            url: __baseUrlWWW + "/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        });

        return false;


    });

</script>
```

And everything would be ok - but when i`m sending this to php, i have problem with reading the post. I have POST in this form

**Firebug return**

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4E16.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 507
        )

)
Array
(
    [userid] => okok@dsada.eu
    [filelabel] => test
    [CustomField] => This is some extra data
)
```

**HTML return in browser new tab**

```
 Array (
[
-----------------------------318572418129603 Content-Disposition:_form - data;
_name] => "userid" okok@dsada.eu
-----------------------------318572418129603 Content-Disposition: form - data;
name = "filelabel" test
-----------------------------318572418129603 Content-Disposition: form - data;
name = "file";
filename = "b24_uam.png" Content-Type: image/png PNG IHDRHHÚőpPLTE˙˙˙UÂÓ~°IDAThíŐAV1Pß˙Ň7lOytŽşP Óü°đňúęľâzý~ŐV\˛O-e'NëC=x3,OdePú>ľ<qł-?× îX~ Wóôą|hÚžŘŇ˘äę~ŚÎÄ_ĺ;5 şÜťk[>Ë:˝^50`ŃÉSKEÖű@ö3v;wK]"kÄ[ŻSÖRyűćŢóö?ÎRy{ÂÇ^lů,á˙ż'îŘň˝Ź-\[ÓĹ(EĺdĎâeWČRÝŽš6z\°6şlÍŘËŹĽ*lÖŕáeZŮR=ĆFÓ50,5É-¨yímŠĘMđ˝1ĺ°ÔeÍ=ÔČRufGŁ`ŠËĺböđŔĺŹĄPöđČňQň-üÄđ×\°$'CvÄ÷Aay*żcÁRŮŠOďÖÝÍm)KFÍć^ [ôżŤŢŕŔčä-uz0óÚojy$_ôtSKMâkDN)¸eŠIüů#jć˝-˘ˇT¤××Žíkźů}b;] => "CustomField" This is some extra data 
#-----------------------------318572418129603-- )
```

And my question is - how to read this in php? Browser in firebug shows in console correct formated arrays - $_post and $_files, but view in browser shows it in this way. Im running it on wamp localhost - but that shouldn be the problem i think?

Comment: What is the problem in php? Not really clear what your issue is

Comment: My problem is that when i use print_r($_POST) i dont see proper array - but still RAW post data - and i cannot use for example $_POST['name'].

Comment: Need more input. :) Ran your code following the example link you provided and all is well. Please post the PHP code and form HTML you are using when you get this condition.

Comment: Notice, the post data is coming through as the index of the first element in, apparently, the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I think i found the answer - new tab is processing the post data so it cannot be displayed this way in new tab by clicking "open in new tab in firebug" on post request..

I think i should give myself a vote down ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code updated

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo" id="fm" action="">
    <label>Your email address:</label>
    <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />
    <label>Custom file label:</label>
    <input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" /><br />
    <label>File to stash:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>



<script>
    $('#fm').on('submit', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
            url: __baseUrlWWW + "/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: true, // this is default so you can remove the line
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
        });

        return false;


    });

</script>
```

The issue is that you are not sending the correct contentType and you are not allowing the call to transform the data you are adding to the querystring.  The form is not posting since you are returning false so you are not sending the contentType that you setup in the form for sending a file upload.  Then you tell the ajax call not to send a contentType in the header.  You need to tell the ajax call you want to send multipart/form-data in the header.  Then processData: true which is default will merge the FormData object into your querystring.

The only reason you are getting the other form data is because you are creating the FormData object using the form you are "submitting".

Comment: Thx @eyegropram but changing that generates console error  
`TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`

Comment: Did you change something else in your code?  Also, it doesn't look like you need $(this)[0] since "this" should already be the form.