# Laravel AJAX form not sending image data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a form I am trying to submit with an image file.

The problem is that no image file is being sent.

My AJAX call:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".hidden-image-upload", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/project/uploadImage',
        data: new FormData($(".hidden-image-upload")[0]),
        headers: {
           'X-CSRF-Token': $('form.hidden-image-upload [name="_token"]').val()
        },
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

And then my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'hidden-image-upload', 'files' => true]) !!}
    {!! Form::file('file', ['class' => 'cover-image-upload-button']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my controller I am just returning:

```
return $request->all();
```

And I am getting:

```
_token: "lFHIf7wiYI3IWqrbcpKxgJEPtXCIVpLm5nVhJ1Ks", file: {}}
_token: "lFHIf7wiYI3IWqrbcpKxgJEPtXCIVpLm5nVhJ1Ks"
file: {}
```

Any help?

Comment: Checkout this post, maybe it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you return the data, it will be displayed as you are getting. Instead, if you use print_r to print the data submitted, you will get something like this:

```
Array ( [_token] => IFQtwfwAKbPs8NJ9Sao4X19Z5bzsPzT0SxL0GaUt [file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => File.csv [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/csv [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 169 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpTT84Kb [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpTT84Kb ) )
```

To save the uploaded file somewhere else, you should access it like this:

```
$request->file('file')
```

[More here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#files)