# Sending file together with form data via ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file via ajax together with some fields in a form. However, it doesn't work. I get this error.

> Undefined Index :- File

Here's my code.

**HTML**

```html
<!-- File Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="file">Upload Software / File</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="price">Price($)</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="price" name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```js
$("#add_product").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  product_name = $("product_name").val();
  //d = $("#add_new_product").serialize();
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: $("#add_new_product").serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      //
      alert(response);

    }
  })
});
```

**PHP**

```php
if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
  echo ":!";
} else {
  echo "ASa";
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously/8758614#8758614

Comment: @M.Doye
The problem here is, I have more data together with the file, which is causing the trouble.

Comment: Serialize function will not include file in data variable there is another mechanism to achive this please google it.

Comment: You can use @M.Doye solution you have to trigger the code while  submitting the form instead of file change event.

Comment: @siddhesh
Could you possibly tell me that **mechanism name** ?

Comment: check out this one it's perfectly matching your requirements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try using `FormData()`:

```
$("form#files").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

The above is a sample code, but you may use it to modify it.

Comment: How to send file and data with the above method

Comment: @annapoorani The HTML is in the question and the jQuery from the answer, that should work. Let me know if you face any difficulties.

Answer (score 11):

you can use FormData

```js
$("#add_product").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fdata = new FormData()

  fdata.append("product_name", $("product_name").val());

  if ($("#file")[0].files.length > 0)
    fdata.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0])
  //d = $("#add_new_product").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: fdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      //
      alert(response);

    }
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- File Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="file">Upload Software / File</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="price">Price($)</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="price" name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

We need to acknowledge first is that **we need to APPEND both Form Input Data and Form File(s) into a single FormData** variable.

Here is my solution in which I have enabled *Multi File* option so that this solution can fit for all examples.

It is *Important* to include **name** attribute in the input controls to make it work properly on server side in most of cases. If you are using C# then you can use simply *Request.Form["nameAttribute"]* to simply get the function. It is similar for Java and other languages.

My Sample Code is

```js
   $(document).ready(function () //Setting up on Document to Ready Function
    {
        $("#btnUpload").click(function (event) {

            //getting form into Jquery Wrapper Instance to enable JQuery Functions on form                    
            var form = $("#myForm1");

            //Serializing all For Input Values (not files!) in an Array Collection so that we can iterate this collection later.
            var params = form.serializeArray();

            //Getting Files Collection
            var files = $("#File1")[0].files;

            //Declaring new Form Data Instance  
            var formData = new FormData();

            //Looping through uploaded files collection in case there is a Multi File Upload. This also works for single i.e simply remove MULTIPLE attribute from file control in HTML.  
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            //Now Looping the parameters for all form input fields and assigning them as Name Value pairs. 
            $(params).each(function (index, element) {
                formData.append(element.name, element.value);
            });

            //disabling Submit Button so that user cannot press Submit Multiple times
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.val("Uploading...");
            btn.prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: "Handler.ashx", //You can replace this with MVC/WebAPI/PHP/Java etc
                method: "post",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function () {
                    //Firing event if File Upload is completed!  
                    alert("Upload Completed");
                    btn.prop("disabled", false);
                    btn.val("Submit");
                    $("#File1").val("");

                },
                error: function (error) { alert("Error"); }

            });

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm1">
    <p><textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20" name="TextArea1"></textarea></p>
    <p><input id="File1" type="file" multiple="multiple" /></p>
    <input id="btnUpload" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

For a working example (asp.net C# with handlers) you can visit sample code on https://github.com/vibs2006/HttpFileHandlerFormDataSample

Comment: Running code snippet gives me this `From an Embedded Page at stacksnippets.net  Error`. Why?

Comment: @Tan thats happening because Server side like that of 'Handler.ashx' cannot be executed under snippet.WHy don't u try the same at your localhost using my github code.

Comment: Can you share your github code that you are referring to? I mean without ASP.NET/C# thing.

Comment: @Tan its already present in the last line of my post. https://github.com/vibs2006/HttpFileHandlerFormDataSample

Comment: One more link https://qawithexperts.com/questions/301/how-to-do-javascript-file-upload

Comment: @prateekkathal Thank you for this script. It is almost exactly what I am looking for. Is there anyway to use the success: function () { to redirect users to a thank you page?

Comment: @5150Design Yes it is very easy. Simply use `window.location.href = "http://your.thank.you.url.com"` in end of your `success` function.

Comment: @vibs2006 Thank you!

Comment: @vibs2006 Any way to ensure that 'required' fields are checked prior to upload?

Comment: @5150-Design pl check https://jqueryvalidation.org/ for all production level validation solutions