# upload large image(5MB) file in less timing

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, joomla

In php, I need to upload an large image; however it needs to upload in minimal seconds.

We have number of fields in a form with image upload. user can upload large images, using normal upload it will take long time. So I would like to use some background uploading using jQuery ajax. please provide some other solutions to make it easy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can send uploaded image to server using JQuery ajax [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761469/sending-file-together-with-form-data-via-ajax-post/33762023#33762023), and you can show uploader image before ajax request and hide it after complete

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: @jogo, Before I tried an normal image upload using php

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), it supports Ajax upload, upload progression, drag & drop files and also multi-file upload.