# Uploading files via AJAX alongside other form elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-data

If I'm uploading a file via AJAX using `FormData()`, can I process that as part of the same form as the rest of my data, or do I need to treat it and the other data as two separate entities? If the latter is the case, should I assume I need two separate AJAX calls?

Comment: Just add the additional data to the formdata?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax