# Get JSON response from Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am not front end developer and I'm spending a quite time trying to do so. Hope you guys can help me.
I have a form which sends files to an API in server, like below:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="url/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">   

      <div class="inputFileCustom">
        <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="uploadFiles" accept="application/pdf"/>
        <label for="uploadFiles">
            <div class="ic-bt ic-bt-details ic-bt-text btn btn-border">
            Choose a file
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

`url/upload` returns a JSON, like:

```
{ "status": "ok"/"fail" }
```

I need two things:

1. Prevent submit to redirect to `url/upload`;
2. Get JSON response from server and, if successful, call `loadFiles()` function (which is already working).

I'm using javascript for `loadFiles()` function, but its very simple.

Comment: please share loadFiles() function

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You can install an event listener on 'submit' for your form and use event.preventDefault() to not call 'url/upload' after submit. Combine it with some AJAJ and you're done.

Comment: @MichaelRöhrig I'm using jQuery and I tried it. But any ajax code worked. Got a Bad Request error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery form handler as,

```
<script>     

    // Attach a submit handler to the form 
  // Attach a submit handler to the form 


$("#uploadForm").submit(function(event) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadFiles", $('[name="file"]')[0].files[0]);
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        loadFiles()
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

    </script>
```

Refer this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. While debugging, when it steps over `var formData...` line, it calls `url/upload`.

Comment: Try removing action and add hard coded URL in Ajax call.

Comment: I did as you said but still not working, it redirects.

Comment: It returns `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I tried change formData for filename but still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you SO much Shankar! Your code update helped me solving my problem! I just had to change `formData.append("uploadFiles"...` to a name which server was waiting.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to post the request using Javascript. If you're using JQuery, you can use `$.ajax` for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: '',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Using this means that it won't redirect the page away from the form, so that you can display success or error messages to the same screen.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information

Comment: That is a server side error, so either its expecting a parameter you're not passing, or it's something else server side. Ajax is the right solution, using the code above it will make a request to the server and log out the response.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41mnz0z1/

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the standard action of the browser after submitting the form (redirecting you to another page). `data: $(this).serialize()` sends the form data to your desired `url: 'fileUpload.php'`.

It works the same with a file.

Comment: This is not working. I don't know how server is getting this request but using `$(this).serialize()` returns an error. If I use filename in URL property (url + fileToPost) it returns Bad Request.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. Prevent submit to redirect to url/upload    

    <form id="uploadForm" action="url/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onsubmit ='return checkRegistration()'>   

              <div class="inputFileCustom">
                <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="uploadFiles" accept="application/pdf"/>
                <label for="uploadFiles">
                    <div class="ic-bt ic-bt-details ic-bt-text btn btn-border">
                    Choose a file
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>


     <script>
        function checkRegistration(){
            if(!form_valid){           
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: This code-only answer doesn't explain what was wrong or how to fix it.