# Handle Json Response after submitting a file to a server

Tags: html, json, ajax

hope you are doing good. I am facing a bit of problem after submitting a file to my server (currently local) and then processing the json response once the file is uploaded. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752937/get-json-response-from-form-submit/35753109) is quite similar to what I'm looking for, and it is working fine, but on submitting the file, it redirects to the json response page.

```
<script>
$("#uploadForm").submit(function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadFiles", $('[name="file"]')[0].files[0]);
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
          //grabe the json response
          //check if the form is successfully submitted
          // if yes then send the name of pdf file
          //grab another json response
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
    </script>
```

and this is the form

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/file/file-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">   

      <div class="inputFileCustom">
        <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="uploadFiles" accept="application/pdf"/>
        <label for="uploadFiles">
            <div class="ic-bt ic-bt-details ic-bt-text btn btn-border">
            Choose a file
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

on submitting the form, the form goes to the `file-upload` page, but I want to handle the Json in the same page. This is the Json response on successful file submit

```
{
    "message": "File successfully uploaded"
}
```

And then the next response which will be received after sending the filename to the server will be like this

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "Section1": {
   "essentialSections": [
    "CAREER OBJECTIVE",
    "PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE",
    "EDUCATION",
    "ADDITIONAL SKILLS"
  ],
  "sectionFontSize": {
    "CAREER OBJECTIVE": "12",
    "PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE": "12",
    "EDUCATION": "12",
    "ADDITIONAL SKILLS": "12"
  },
   "spaceBetweenSections": {
    "CAREER OBJECTIVE": "8",
    "PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE": "4",
    "EDUCATION": "1",
    "ADDITIONAL SKILLS": "4"
  }
  },
  "Section2":{
   "totalSpaces": 347,
  "totalNewLines": 90,
  "totalCharacter": 1674
  },
  "Section3":{
  "totalNoPages": 1,
   "pdfContainImage": false,
    "textColorInPdf": "Black"
  },
  "Section4":{
   "allTextSizeAndStyle": {
    "all_text_font_size_same": "False",
    "all_text_font_type_same": "False"
  },
  "headerFooterSpace": {
    "Header Space Count": "4",
    "Footer Space Count": "5"
  }
  }
}
```

I just want to know how I can catch the json response in the same page, and then send some more info to the server and catch another json response. Thanks