# Execute php file while running html

Tags: php, html

I have some problems here:

> I have **index.html**, that contains **upload** file feature
>
> I have **cleaning.php**, it will **cleaning** every string in a file

So, what I want is if I run index.html then upload a file, at that time it will execute cleaning.php and return the clean file to index.html
How can I do that?
Need your help :(

This is my index.html file:

```
 <script>
 $(function testing (data) {

    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
       // I want to pass this array to cleaning.php
       $someArray[] = "stringFromCSVFile"; // must pass to cleaning.php
  });
 </script>
```

This is my cleaning.php file:

```
$array = csvToArray("filecsv.csv"); //convert uploaded file to array
callFuncA($array);

functionA($array){
   return $something;
}
```

Comment: Share your code with us

Comment: I would use Ajax for that

Comment: How'd you expect us to help or see what you have done wrong with 0 code added :|

Comment: Use Ajax, while uploading a file from index.html and post that file to cleaning.php and get your proper response via ajax.

Comment: and what is your **cleaning.php** content?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax post for files this way and you can do changes in cleaning.php as your requirements and return your response to index.html.

**index.html** **file:**

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var files;
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
function prepareUpload(event){
  files = event.target.files;
}
$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);
function uploadFiles(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value){
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cleaning.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //Successfuly Uploaded
            $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('#response').html('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**cleaning.php** **file:**

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) but when I test to run the code, it doesn't give me an output :(

Comment: You can easily run this code and you can clean file after upload in cleaner.php.

Comment: actually my limitation: file that can be upload are just .csv file. And I already store those csv string in `someArray[]` in javascript and ready to pass into php. Is there another solution for my case?

Comment: Its better, you can pass file to cleaner.php and generate array using php and return back your response as you needs.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible, ajax cannot read the contents of uploaded files.

You should put an upload form in index.html and submit it to cleaning.php which does cleaning in PHP and returns the result.

Comment: Ajax can read the contents of uploaded file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/2893691

Comment: @Dave It uses FormData , part of HTML5, which causes compatibility problems with IE < 10.