# node.js instead of redirect show alert message

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a node.js code which is basically uploading a file to desired folder. the code is as shown below:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream('./python_codes/' + filename); 
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.send('upload succeeded!');
            console.log("fileuploaded")
        });
    });
});
```

but on clicking the upload button on client side it is redirecting to new page. instead of redirecting I want to show a alert message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make the form target a hidden iframe, and then respond with markup that includes a `<script>` tag with `alert()` call in it. I've never done something like this, but maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using `form` with `method=POST` and `action='/upload'`to upload the file. When submitted it'll take you to new page with content "upload succeeded!"

To remain on the same page use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) on client side to make the POST request. Upon success you can show the server response as alert message.

You can refer:

[Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

[jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)