# Submit form data and upload using Ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

First of all i am beginner to php. here is the table structure of table "post"

[image]

```
<form method="post" action="postStatus.php">

 <textarea rows="3" name="con" id="con" placeholder="what do you think?"></textarea><br>

  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="img" id="img>
  <button name="post" id="post"> Post > </button>
 </form>
```

postStatus.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
require_once '../log/class.user.php'; 
$user_home = new USER(); 

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in()) 
{ 
    $user_home->redirect('../log/index.php'); 
} 

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession'])); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$userid = $row['userID']; 
$postid = microtime(); 
$con = $_POST['con']; 
($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")); 
mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], vaistra); 

if(isset($_POST['post'])) 
{ 
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO post (`postId`, `userId`, `content`, `timeStamp`) VALUES ('$postid', '$userid', '$con', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"); 
} 
header('Location: user_wall.php'); 
?>
```

i have to insert submit data to this table using this form. one input field for content column and file upload file upload in directory and path must be stored in database according to file type. like if uploaded file is a video then path must be stored in video column. postId and userId field is auto generated .

thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Question Updated please check. I'm happy you again on my thread. Thanks @MuhammadAkberKhan

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Where is your AJAX code?

Comment: i dont know how to upload file and save path in Database. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Research file uploads with PHP first. The file will be uploaded to a temp folder, and you'll need code to move it to the folder you want it stored in. There will be an array listing info about each file uploaded where you can get the info about the file. Too much left to do for a SO question until you do a bit more research.

Comment: these links might be help you, 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/2940521  2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/2940521 3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981045/2940521

Comment: Thanks bhai. I am really appreciate your help.   @MuhammadAkberKhan