# File upload in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload file using ajax in codeigniter framework. My code work without using ajax but when i use ajax i got error message 'Undefined index: picture'in if($_FILES['picture']['name']).

Please check this code

View :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="int">Picture</label>
      <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" class="dropify" data-height="300" />
   </div>
</form>
```

AJAX :

```
var picture=new FormData( $("#picture")[0] );
var url = "<?php echo site_url('Workscontroller/create_action'); ?>";  
            $.ajax({
              url:url,
              data: {"title":title,"caption":caption,"description":description,"kategori":kategori,"picture":picture},
              dataType:"JSON",
              type:"POST",
              mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
              contentType: false,  
              cache: false,  
              processData:false,  
              success:function(data){  
               swal("Berhasil ditambahkan!", "Anda berhasil menambahkan porto folio.", "success")
               window.location.replace(data.url);
           }  
       });
```

Controller :

```
$this->load->library('upload');
   $this->_rules();
    $nmfile = "file_".time(); //nama file saya beri nama langsung dan diikuti fungsi time
    $config['upload_path'] = './works/'; //path folder
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
    $config['max_size'] = '2048'; //maksimum besar file 2M
    $config['max_width']  = '2000'; //lebar maksimum 1288 px
    $config['max_height']  = '2000'; //tinggi maksimu 768 px
    $config['file_name'] = $nmfile; //nama yang terupload nantinya
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if($_FILES['picture']['name'])
    {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
        {
           $gbr = $this->upload->data();
           $data = array(
              'title' => $this->input->post('title',TRUE),
              'caption' => $this->input->post('caption',TRUE),
              'description' => $this->input->post('description',TRUE),
              'picture' => $gbr['file_name'],
              'kategori' => $this->input->post('kategori',TRUE),
              );
           $this->WorksModel->insert($data);
       }
   }
   else{

   }
```

Comment: send file using ajax doesnt same like post method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax should be a good reference

Comment: You can get reference from here http://www.roytuts.com/ajax-file-upload-using-codeigniter-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `formData` should be an HTML `<form>` element. That is most easily done by giving the `<form>` an id attribute.

view:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='myForm'>
```

The ajax then changes to

```
var formData = new FormData($("#myForm")[0]);
```

In the javascript you don't show how the values for `title`, `caption`, `description`, and `kategori` are set. But they are clearly other `<input>` elements in the form. You probably do not need to capture these values separately because all form inputs (including FILE type inputs) are captured in `var formData`.  That means that the ajax `data` option can be rewritten from

```
data: {"title":title,"caption":caption,"description":description,"kategori":kategori,"picture":picture},
```

to

```
data: formData,
```

The line `if($_FILES['picture']['name'])` should work now.

Answer (score 0):

//update like this

var url = "";
            $.ajax({
              url:url,
              data:"title":title,"caption":caption,"description":description,"kategori":kategori,"picture":picture},
              dataType:"JSON",
              type:"POST",
              mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
              contentType: false,
              async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
              success:function(data){
               swal("Berhasil ditambahkan!", "Anda berhasil menambahkan porto folio.", "success")
               window.location.replace(data.url);
           }
       });