# $_FILES is not populated with file when called through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using simple ajax call to submit form data where I am trying to POST some form inputs along with an file.

```
    $("#submit-uploaded-audio").on("click", function () {
    var post_data = new FormData();
    var file = $("#audio_file").prop('files')[0];

    post_data.append('key1', 'value1');
    post_data.append('key2', 'value2');
    post_data.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/process_audio_upload",
        type: "POST",
        data: post_data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // some logic
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // some logic here
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax call goes to the server url (codeigniter framework) but **data posted in call is not getting populated into $_POST as well as $_FILES (both arrays are empty)**

Checked php.ini settings and file upload settings looks good

However, "php://input" shows required data in raw format

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I want to get this data into respective $_POST and $_FILES array so that I can do further actions.

Thanks in advance.

Also tried following solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/4349933

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/4349933

Comment: Does `console.log(post_data)` display the data you want to _POST_?

Comment: please show your full html form

Comment: @CPHPython Yes, it does also transfer required data to server. but in raw input stream instead of super-global variables $_POST & $_FILES

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to the `post_data` variable being empty, since you are creating an empty `FormData` and then it may be attempting to append through [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which was designed to append HTML elements...

Try simply doing:

```
post_data.key1 = 'value1';
post_data.file = file;
console.log(post_data);
```

And that should return:

```
FormData {key1: "value1", file: {...}}
```

If the [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) is not working properly, I'd try not using jQuery just for a test and do [Javascript default requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

### *Edit*: Test if the URL is the right one

Since the `post_data` seems to be alright, then perform a POST request through another website (e.g. [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/)) by using the same URL, i.e. `yourdomain.here/process_audio_upload`. If nothing comes back, it's likely that the URL routing is the issue.

Comment: I used suggested way to create FormData obj. It prints all key-value as expected in my console but still no data received at server end.

Comment: Using your browser's Developer Tools is another way to see what is being sent to what url. Check the request headers.

Comment: If you see the question, I have mentioned that I am getting the data into input stream at server end. Its just an issue that data is raw and I need to get it in $_POST and $_FILES for further processing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#submit-uploaded-audio").on("click", function () {
    var post_data = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById('audio_file').files[0];

    post_data.append('key1', 'value1');
    post_data.append('key2', 'value2');
    post_data.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
    url: "/process_audio_upload",
    method: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // some logic
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // some logic here
    }

    });
});
```

Now try by printing print_r($_FILES) and print_r($_POST)

I noticed you are using 'type' parameter instead 'method'. So try this code. I have made few changes.

Comment: no success. Still getting empty arrays for both $_FILES and $_POST. Also tried changing "type" to "method"

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the formData object by passing the `<form>` element to the constructor.  For instance, given this html

```
<form id='a-form' ...>
```

and assuming that `key1` and `key2` are the names of `<input>` elements in the `<form>` do this

```
$("#submit-uploaded-audio").on("click", function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('a-form');
    var post_data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
    url: "/process_audio_upload",
    method: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    //etc ...
```

Good docs [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

After lot of hassle on this, I actually ended up with workaround.
Now I am directly uploading file to **S3 bucket** using ***"dropzone js"*** library and which in-turns places file to S3 bucket.

If needed to manipulate file info or store file meta-data on server (like size, name etc) - I am using *on_success* callback handler of dropzone which can pass on control to server (AJAX call) and access previously uploaded S3 file to further manipulate.

**NOTE**: I know this may not be the answer for question, but that's what I did. I hope it helps if someone is in same situations and none of the above answers helped you.