# How to submit a form with multiple fields having a same name attribute using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML form

```
<html>
<head></head>
<form>
     <input type="text" name="question[]" />
     <input type="text" name="question[]" />
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit" name="save" /> 
</form>
</html>
```

Now to submit form with ajax
I have ajax code but its not working. It's get only one value.

```
$("#submit").click(function() { 
    var que_id  = $("input[type='text'][name='question[]']").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST", 
       url:  "action.php",
       data: {"que_id": que_id},
       success: function(result) {
       $("#question_wrap").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Answer (score -1):

Send form data to php file using ajax

1. add enctype to your form

   ```
   <form id="questionForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="text" name="question[]" />
       <input type="text" name="question[]" />
       <input type="file" name="image" />
       <input type="submit" name="save" />
   </form>
   ```
2. Pass form data to php file using serialize

   ```
   $.ajax({
    url: 'action.php',
    data: $("#questionForm").serialize(),
    method: "post",
    success: function (result) {
            $("#question_wrap").html(result);
          }
   });
   ```
3. access form values in PHP file using the field name

   ```
   <?php 
      foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $value){
            // your logic
      }
     $filedata= $_FILES['image'];
   ?>
   ```