# Uploading both data and files in one form using POST method, AJAX and jQuery (Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. `formData.append("id_element",1)` doesn`t add the field into formData. I have found a lot of solves but in my case it doesn`t work right.

PHP code here:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

```js
$("#hw-upload_image-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append("id_element",1); // doesn`t work here
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            url:$(this).prop('action'),
            data:formData,
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data); // show returned data from php
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<form action="action.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hw-upload_image-form">
    <input type="file" name="hwImage"> <!-- hw = homework (just for you :) -->
</form>
```

---

Result (from the console)

```
array(1) {
  ["hwImage"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(70) "73b38ef5d1f5849ea800c18990acde94_ce_1920x1200x0x0_cropped_800x427.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(36) "D:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\php9F48.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(68411)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: You removed (stealth edit) a `console.log()` line that would actually be quite helpful in debugging.  What was the result/output of that line?

Comment: I removed it, because the output was: https://ibb.co/KN3bMyC (random site for share images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already undestood my mistake.

`$_FILES` will show me only file data, but if I want to see `id_element` I have to use `$_POST`.

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  ["id_element"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```