# AJAX returns undefined when trying to send File to controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have written this AJAXUpload method in a cshtml file in my C# MVC project:

```
function AjaxUpload(url, method, data, successFunction, errorFunction, skipErrorDlg) {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: method,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', GlobalAuthToken);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            successFunction(data);
        },
        error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML file component:

```
<input type="file" class="file" id="attachment" style="display: none;" onchange="fileSelected(this)" accept=".csv"/>
```

This is my Javascript from where I am calling this above method:

```
function fileSelected(input) {
    console.log("Chosen file: " + input.files[0].name);

    var data1 = new FormData();
    data1.append("ImportedFile", input.files[0]); 


    AjaxUpload('/Zetes.ZWS.Processes.Rest/api/importbundles',
        'POST',
        data1,
        function () {
            console.log("Import completed");
        }); 
}
```

However, I am always getting undefined error while invoking this AJAX.
So, I just tried hit-and-trial method and found out that when I use  `processData: false` it causes undefined exception.

So, I tried to remove this line too. That gives me `Illegal Invocation Exception`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with remove dataType: 'json. It will work. I have working code of same. If you want I can share this.

Comment: @NaveenSoni, I will check and let u know very soon

Comment: @NaveenSoni, I tried with keeping processData: false, and removing dataType: 'json'; doesn't work :( . Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Okay!! What is the inside in the method variable. "POST" ??

Comment: yes. it is POST

Answer (score 0):

You will have rearrange attribute this postion as like my code. Its working in my application.Hope it will help you.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         success: function (data) {
           successFunction(data);
         },
         error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
           console.log(thrownError);
         }
 });
```

also you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax/10899796#10899796)

Comment: I tried exactly your solution. It is still error for me. May some setting is missing which is not allowing me to use processData: false?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is not working too. I am starting to believe that there must be some other problem with the framework I am working on which might be preventing me sending files to server or something like that