# Sending json with files nested in lists with ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I am developping a form with some basic inputs and a mini form (in a popup) with a list of foos and each foo have its own attachement file

```
{

    // form fields
    ...

    foos: [
        {
            // foo form fields
            ...

            attachment: { /* File type */ }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

before i add the attachement property (file upload), everything work good when i submit the whole form with `axios` to the backend api server (i am using `redux-form` to manage the form state)

I use `JSON.stringify(formValues)` to send data with `axios` as `json`

But when i add the attachement property i don't know how to send the form because i read that with the file involved in the form i can't no longer send the form as json but I have to use `FormData`

The problem is I have nested file objects within a list so how can i send the whole form ?

Comment: You can't mix file data with json string because it's not the way it works. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010519/1832330 is your best bet.

Comment: If you're willing to cast to and from base64, your approach should work

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/6431689 and below my answer

Answer (score 3):

I achieved the same as this.

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", file);

//here my formData is in JSON format
formData.append("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));

const config = {
    method: "POST", //change according to your API
    data: formData,
    url: api, //API Url
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    }
  };

axios
  .request(config)
  .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: i have file nested in a list you solution doesn't work and the content-type in the header must not be motioned

Comment: In my case, the file is stored in state, separate from form-data, so if you try with separate list of files and form data then it should work. I don't know how JSON.stringify() will work on files.

Comment: It's not my case @SameerRezaKhan if you look at my question they are not separated

Comment: I tried this `file = new File(['foo','baar'], 'foobar.txt'); console.log(JSON.stringify(file));` and it gave me an empty object. and it yielded this `{ }`, but when i just wrote `console.log(file)` i saw all the file's properties.

Comment: So keep them in a separate list with id's of foos, this is what I think you can do.

Comment: the foo are not created yet in the database to have an id

Comment: There must be something unique for each foo which will give you id in your backend. You can use that to name your attachment or can append that with the file name. Anyway you will store them only after you have an id for a foo, right?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that not separate file and other properties

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a state variable `Images` which is an array type.
2. On change of file input assign files to `Images` array (handleOptionImages()).
3. Append this `Images` array in the formData object along with other form data.
4. Finally, send the formData object in your axios request.

   ```
   <form>
   <input type="file" onChange={e =>this.handleOptionImages(e)}>
   <input type="file" onChange={e =>this.handleOptionImages(e)}>
   <input type="text" name="user" value={this.state.value} onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e)}>
   <button onClick={e=>submitForm(e)}>submit</button>
   </form>
   ```

   `define a constructor with blank state like`

   `constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         user:"",
         Images:[]
       }
     }`

   ```
     handleChange = e => {
       this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
     };

     handleOptionImages(e) {
       let Images = this.state.Images.slice();
       let media = e.target.files[0];
       Images[] = media; // Update it with the modified email.
       this.setState({ Images: Images });
     }
     submitForm(e){
       let formdata = new FormData();
       formdata.append("user",this.state.user);
       if (this.state.Images) {
         for (const file of this.state.Images) {
             formdata.append("Images[]", file);
           }
       }

     // add your axios code 
     axios.post("your api path", formdata)
       .then(res => {
           //handle success
         } else {
           // handle error
         }
       });
     }
   ```

Please have a look I hope it will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set a content-type you need to pass a file-like object. You can create one using a Blob.

```
const obj = {
  hello: "world"
};
const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
const blob = new Blob([json], {
  type: 'application/json'
});
const data = new FormData();
data.append("document", blob);
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/sample',
  data: data,
})
```

[jQuery + Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10899796/6431689) for more details refer link

```
$("form#data").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
});
```