# how did i can send form data with $.post()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I can send form_data for uploaded file with $.ajax. but when I used (input: file) how did I can send form data that be an image file that chose with input to PHP with $.post()?

```
<input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg" style="display: none">
```

Comment: please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax) to post file data

Comment: that link uses $ajax, I want $.post() method. @MNJ

Comment: `$.post()` is just shorthand for `$.ajax({ method: "post", ... })`

Comment: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: @Andreas  thanks I know that but I didn't know how to write with $.post() method!!!!

Comment: It's literally just `$.post({ /* and here the same options as you would use with $.ajax() */ })` o.O -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings

Comment: @Andreas you don't understand my question! if it's simply writing code with $.post. thank you. and don't get links and others

Comment: Spend some time actually reading the content behind the links I've posted. They contain all you need to know...

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make the method of form `POST` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form method="POST" action="URL" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Then You can get the uploaded image as `$_FILES` where your form is posting.

Comment: thanks for answering, but how did I can write without form tag, and in jquery and with post() method? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg">
```

You'll need to get the `file` by `onchange` event of `input`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img').change(function(){
        var file_data = $('#img').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "fileUpload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: _"But I need $.post()"_ comment incoming in 3, 2, 1, ...

Comment: $.post() method is just the shorthand of $.ajax() with method POST, It'll work like this when you're talking about formdate or image upload.

Comment: That's what I've told OP in the comments below his question. Didn't help anything yet^^

Comment: when i wrote
$.post('file.php',
          {
             data: data
           },
           function(data){  }
)
i could n't wrote      this tree options :  
             ((contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false))
I did n't know how to write this