# Disable Form Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have this form, that uploads a file to a third party host, upload works fine, but I'm getting a redirect when upload is done, I have read that Ajax can solve this, but I have tried many Ajax solutions and non seem to have worked, might it be because the action is done outside of my website? any help is much appreciated!

```
<form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://website/upload/01" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="XXXXXXX">
    <input name="file" type="file">
         <input value="Upload" type="submit">
```

Comment: Please add the ajax code and specify where is the issue you have faced.

Comment: _“might it be because the action is done outside of my website?”_ - if you want to make an AJAX request to a different website (different _origin_, technically) - then the remote endpoint must explicitly make this possible, using a mechanism called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, CORS for short. We have no idea whether that is the case here, or not.

Comment: CBroe answered the Question, it was not possible due to CORS! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault();`

Here i attached sample code with Jquery and ajax.

**jQuery + Ajax**

```
 $("form#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.pathname, // location of form submit
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
```

Reference: [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)