# I can't pass values from JS to a PHP form using POST method

Tags: javascript, php, forms

How to upload files from this form to the form that sends the message. Currently, the message is being sent, but no files
I can't pass values from JS to a form in

My website: https://fck-auto.de/ankaufahrzeuge/

FORM: https://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/2nzL9f7g/

PHP CODE:

```
if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){

    $rand = rand();

    $createFolder = uniqid();
    mkdir('uploads/'.$createFolder);

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {

        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if($tmpFilePath != ""){

            $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            $explode = explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
            $filePath = "uploads/".$createFolder. '/' . rand().'.'.$explode[1];

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                $files[] = $shortname;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Ex :

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you submit using AJAX refer

[Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](http://Check%20you%20have%20enctype=%22multipart/form-data%22%20in%20your%20form.%20%20Ex%20:%20%20%3Cform%20action=%22#%22%20method=%22post%22%20enctype=%22multipart/form-data%22%3E%20%20If%20you%20submit%20using%20AJAX%20refer%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)