# How to upload document and other JSON string using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, csrf

I'd like to do some file upload with some JSON string to my controller. This is my current AJAX

```
var data_upload = new FormData(); 

$.each($(".uploads")[0].files, function(i, file) {
   data_upload.append('input_upload_file['+i+']', file);
});

$.ajax({
    url         : url,                      
    type        : 'POST',
    async       : false,
    enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',
    dataType    : 'JSON',
    data        : { upload_data     : data_upload ,
                    json_string1    : $('#myjson_string1').val(),
                    json_string2    : $('#myjson_string2').val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : csrfHash 
                  }
    })
    .done(function(data){
                    
        alert("Success");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    
        alert("Fail");
    });
```

This is my HTML form (simplified):

```
<body>
     <form id="uploadMe">
      
        <label class="fileContainer">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myName" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myAge" />
        <input type="file" class="uploads" name="input_upload_file[]" multiple />
        <input type="file" class="uploads" name="input_upload_file[]" multiple />
        <input type="text" class="json_string" id="myjson_string1" name="json_string1" />
        <input type="text" class="json_string" id="myjson_string2" name="json_string2" />
    </label>                       
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    <?php
    
         $token_name = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
         $token_hash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
    
         echo "<input type='hidden' id='csrf_name' name='".$token_name."' value='".$token_name."' />";
         echo "<input type='hidden' id='csrf_hash' name='".$token_hash."' value='".$token_hash."' />";
    ?>
  </body>
```

I also need to send the CSRF token with my AJAX upload. Currently, it's not working at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax) 
You can use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

```
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('upload_data',$('#myjson_string1').val())
    form.append('csrfHash','csrfHash_here')

    $.ajax({
    url         : url,                      
    type        : 'POST',
    async       : false,
    enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',
    dataType    : 'JSON',
    data        : { 
                    
                    upload_data     : data_upload ,
                    json_string1    : $('#myjson_string1').val(),
                    json_string2    : $('#myjson_string2').val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : csrfHash 
                  }
    })
    .done(function(data){
                    
        alert("Success");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    
        alert("Fail");
    });
```

Add properties to ajax

```
 processData: false,
 contentType: false,
```