# How to send form data and file in csv using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ZWg.png)
So, this is the payload and I am trying send form data along with the file but using form.serialize is formatting the csv file as well, any suggestion on how it can be sent without affecting the file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkHJD.png)

Comment: you need to use `multipart/form-data`

Comment: tries, but then it changes the request format,

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: great, thanks, will try it out, and since looks like it is duplicate to that, will delet this one

Comment: Yes a duplicate - see the accepted answer (it is a multipart/form-data form)