# how to upload an image via ajax in Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent

I've a html page with a form with some input, including a file.

I'm trying to post and save this to a API endpoint done in Laravel 8, but I can't get the data inside the controller.

My html/JS is:

```html
<form class="row align-items-center g-1 product-edit-form" id="product-edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <label for="product-edit-form__code">Codice</label>
        <input type="text" disabled class="form-control-plaintext" name="code" id="product-edit-form__code" value="11111" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <label for="product-edit-form__quantity">Quantità</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"  name="quantity" id="product-edit-form__quantity" value="10" step="1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 offset-3">
        <label for="product-edit-form__image_input" class="form-label">Immagine</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="image" id="product-edit-form__image_input" type="file" accept="image/*"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Aggiorna prodotto</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>


  const productEditFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('fileData', e.target.elements.image.files[0]);
    formData.append('name', e.target.elements.quantity.value);

    try {
      // Set API url.
      const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/product/11111?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM';
      // Create options for the fetch function.
      const options = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: formData,
        dataType: 'json', // also tried without 
      };

      // Get a response from the API.
      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);
      // Parse response into JSON.
      return await response.json();
    }
    catch (error) {
      // Print catched error to the console.
      console.log('(App) Error occured while getting data.', error);
    }
  }

  document
    .querySelector('#product-edit-form')
    .addEventListener("submit", productEditFormSubmit, false);

</script>
```

The method in the controller:

```php
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Product $product, Request $request)
    {
        $test = $request->allFiles(); // empty
        $test2 = $request->all(); // empty
        $test3 = $request->file('fileData'); // empty
        $test4 = $request->getContent(); // string with bad data
    }
```

I've tried to look for the various answer on Stackoverflow and internet about.
Pretty much every one say to use `FormData` to pass the data but no one works, when I try to get the value inside the controller returns null\empty. I've tried to post the form both with pure JS and Jquery. The user is anonymous.

Please note: `$request->getContent()` returns a string with "bad" formatted data, where at least I can get the reference\value of "quantityField" - the other is certainly the file data. Therefore, the data is passed to the backend. How can I actually get it in a working way? (and save to a file\inside the server?)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileData"; filename="myw3schoolsimage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

���� JFIF   d d  �� Ducky     <  �� Adobe d�   �� �         





��  � h �� �                                 a!1AQq��"�S���2BR#T�3�br���V�s$dt����        !1Qq���2RAa"�#����Bbr��   ? �� >;��ב���Lߝl;WX��_� A�T⇭�p\�e�%4,^w��>�����Ũ̇j)�D�``��5�ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������ۧ�������?����gx=k�WQ8��C���yv��t� �����tV'j�%w��*�qJB5!��m���!��T
@�=m�䮌���<Eܕ��T��B>a��-6�� Gs��_O�V�|!p
>��\O�.�� ���i���4�B�|!p
>�͋R��zX��$;O_L�#)��f�"�ꁱ޴��W�.w���������a��\M�.�� �a�i���4�B�L|8����Jf�
k}9ۋ�hl!)
�{>�#\X�ހ�]��?xkbi���7zď^����Gr�I�;`���BX�����I[v�[��:|��H���Bww�����j�қy�QI>��3������8�S���Њ�u����7ն�vhq�at�M̲�}T��Q�����$�
�O=�{2�p���Q��/���j4�E.�� �a�i���4�B�l!p2S۞��j��gy奶�9�(�9�R�;cdm:��h���?����%�}\\p�����$;#�ōB)+��k��U�÷�m۪YV�Ά3 �   G�\���{8��ݎ��!��o��P�ږg2ژ�(8e���G�d�"������m�o�4�[�*:�Ks
>��+@$���3&x��vm����%2E�ͥ��v�S`���n��߼�PR�s�>c�f�r��Y˻��X��xP�p�WT�B"��<�Z���CI��2���a���R���� 9�ap.��_O����� ";�� �w�ZҚ�Z>_u�����>�Ie��YFiL�r�8����
�t�En�nT�]��r��KU�(��ZXXN`.#����I�.������� �W��v�~�� е�%�+��nG�[v�����9�:�*�9�9r��&[��IQ������,cĻ9j~�yڂÓ���r�R��J:�=    p�9'xmz�㮶�����N�pS*3mCʟ�<���Y�4�l#�$;l�{ݶ�4��������-()s���)�F�&D�GWG�49{�m���|ܳ �k�5�,�P|��^G3��8e=L��a;�'�m������:KX/��fb���>�? 1�r�ny�D�N�}��a��VF�J�� ����D�Ys��+Umª�BJ�yǈ��~����V�I�Q٫�\
��;R�2i
Y'Ȑa��T����*��ѮRtt�EM�ik�%��9�y��r��\K�[ږ"�/x3wz��P�.vꇛ(<�e.(!iU���v�9E���a    �
˳���-]i��o�/��u�c��7϶�UI �
>mδ�¯��?+7��_��_�xW�ȴ�퍝`�T�f�O�nK�P���˖ew`8G?��"�H�qޖz
�Ga}`Tդ���V�e�B�s�����M�#�c|_�EL��gط-"i�,����d�ʮ<����m��
Ƽ�I3��kd���'���8��E���a�X�SCk�M5:L�Lʔ��KQ��q1�b�j�TE�@�aެ�ۜ۴.VՌ��I��'�A�s���|�:�i�Q�ۏ���"�e!��;qC�,�V�����{|^E�j;� @�vr��s��R��j�}M��R����6G�iѩ?'ĚY�d�Ӷ���h��îںK8�II'�(���ɥI���S7�M�$�_S��͹y��#���~�M���-���ժ�e\C��b��)�8���j�V���W5*���r���:��+qՒT��Lt����ޥI���f�ma��Ʉ !�(��a\����ۜ�
�W.��D���t��ꞧ�2�S�����:yY7�������ŵ��ZW�WQ�`���3�8[�u�j�V���W�6�)�V��R֢I$�$���Ĩ�|".ʞ� �锕1s�o �@y� ;%9J7��"�)v�R����z˕R-�T�:Z�s�'�`p���-�$���-<w����Yrܗ&)P��C�*RP��+%KR�B@��b�L�Q闉�50/l�5lR2Y����M�4��瘡D'�=��QT�}
?A��y���Լ�Y�}�K/���e3�$�)��7ŲnV���z4�t�A��N��]='@:�X&���8�����S�ˌ��[L�J4��
4��Ƞ�;Z����K�}&�q!N~͕ �<�D��#M+s��O^��h\��MPA�z�κí��Z�J�
�]����Z4��M��2���Si���]2jj�i����Y��e��-�e%)%Kc*U��E{r�����P��G6\� ���U����=���Ǝ]kĊ��c�[����B��A<'Â���F���D�ȟB:���Ba��Z/�ՠ��T�I�o������x�������k渾�ݧJ��B��M�T�
T�JPRq������Z�\����x��kn��֩��KO�Z� I�gC�(ʆf�[�ln��5(�����#��ZhMF4�V�U�q5u��!���Q�eY�x�<3��ݗ:�KT���č��KIGj�,��J�ƪ��f�\��TϬ�;Di��F�h����A)���
�Ҋ6m���LU�]@KjQ閲$ �UG������
�ƛJW:��4���{5��Ž5.7QT��*}(IKt�+J�fW*$y"!�ōR4��Nu�QQ���F���
MC4�UK�E6���>� (���\�O�A�N�JRn��^/��Ί�D��j�LΖ��H 2���fI�8d#[�Gt�E[��1]K�@ � ����;��me���S��TVۉ��g�r�.�#���ᛒU���L�Q��GQR�����V����kE�Zs�����H���~]9Md��W�/�{�!�)����G��%$�Y�G^P>o]� ���|�v� v��L� �=H��B�2TA
��!P*   �����v۪���    �B���c�r�s�c��p����2'ͺۨK�,-�qJ�A`Dz��IUj�i��K�D��p��$�eX��h�����eOT��ZO�Z�H��re��t@�w���u=��JhC͗\"E��LyM� 7�ӎ<~K�_N�nU#���t���T%��Zg�Vs��Tt���y��}���Y"�  , @ J qIq�ђi*]b|�kRA�cl[����q�d�~wf�"_0z^Y<r�)��ț������^z��}������d�9�ɹu�8�ҹUy�aeo"r�@�� N5�bs��R�dn����MU2��{c,��.$v*]��ǰ漩n>��5�k(ԮklWJ'KU4�J�bd��L���������|����r�d�#?i��.�E��{��&�/�]�P4U^�~ɇ���c

W�_�a�2�e�������&�/�]�P4U^�~��D�L��v1@�����'�i��.�(.��ܯ�0��}2�d�45>�~ɇ���c"�zK-ʭ���R� }_�R�=�i�(�h�hlߔ�����C*�)l|{Tc�r�S���~��[���Y��Q@�V����|��%��.Ĵ�Ҏ�ZK�-�p��4�B�\"m�д�д�ZK�-���}a�>�E+�+m\R����>��`��FJ0�4WT�2�,RkVZ|"��|!@.�ZHi���4�B�.�ZO�- QLI�'�����VZ���?����� _�O���v(av�R؞P�ޞ?TU�hP��/6��*�b���~�<�Y�Q�X��Py�ah
0]>6��a@�|!h
>�����5*��y���0�&e))&Qz��]�|�[�=������$�x��> P߮O��p���G�Q4ә�#�
 
���0���%��v�τ( ��9�N 3�\!@d�����Zt�(HL�=ŀ�" p�� 8@ �� � � p� ��
------WebKitFormBoundaryB1hchGuFjUbD9Br4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantityField"

10
------WebKitFormBoundaryB1hchGuFjUbD9Br4--
```

edit:

this is the working code for me:

```
  $.ajax({ //todo riuscire a far funzionare il backend con una funzione fetch JS
    url: ajaxUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
      window.location.href = `#/product/${data.code}`;
    },
    error: function (data) {
      const errors = data.responseJSON.error;
      let message = 'Errore: '
      if (typeof errors === 'string' || errors instanceof String) {
        message += errors;
      }
      else {
        $.each(errors, function (key, error) {
          message += error + '\r\n';
        });
      }
      alert(message)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
```

The main point that didn't work was to use a `PATCH` method instead of a POST. Using POST correctly populated the request data in the Laravel endpoint.

Comment: Check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add this line to your header, please!

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'`

```
  const options = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    body: formData,
    dataType: 'json', // also tried without 
  };
```

```
I would prefer to set the method to POST.
```

Comment: I "solved" the problem before of the answer but it points the things that certainly didn't work: it it necessary to use POST, with PATCH for some reason the data isn't passed

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action',
    data: data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data', //<---
    // continue ...
```

Comment: I tried to add `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'`  to the `fetch` options, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything, `$request->getContent()` remains that string and others method I listed keep return empty.

Comment: oh you have to use `$request->all()` or `$request->file()` to read files -- [check laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files)

Comment: Both `$request->all()` and `$request->file('fileName`)` return empty :( . I wonder, is maybe there some setting\configuration of Laravel that I don't know necessary to let it work\accept form data from a decoupled service?