# Html submit a form, but stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a form with HTML, that when submitting it will run a javascript function (the function itself needs to contact a local server (localhost:...)), but when inside the javascript function I use window.open(...) a new tab is opened. 
I want the form to be submitted but not to change the current page, meaning to stay on the form. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form and stay on same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733808/submit-form-and-stay-on-same-page)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `type="submit"` but want to stay on the same page you could try changing the input type to button so that it would read...

```
input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"
```

and in the function call the box variables with...

```
var name = document.formName.boxName.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `target` for your form:

```
<form target="_blank" action="http://example.com">.....
```

Comment: Can I use the action to call a javascript function?