# Listening for form submit -> file download Event

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, download, blockui

In a JSP file, I have this simple form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="extract_form">
```

and based on a few `select` parameters, it returns a .zip file through this piece of code in the Servlet:

```
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFile.getName() + "\"");
```

-followed by some `sos.write(byteArray);`

All this is working excellent, but the time it takes to create the zip file is dependent on the form parameters and I would like to display a "Please Wait" blockUI popup on form submit and then this is removed again automatically when the .zip file has been received by the browser.

I have no trouble displaying the popup, but I have a hard time getting it to disappear again automatically after file is received! How do I accomplish this?

If have tried the following:

1: Explicit `$.unblockUI()` in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... }
```

-but the ready() event is not triggered after .zip file sent, i.e., the .jsp is not reloaded.

2: A solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733808/submit-form-and-stay-on-same-page). The success callback function is called, but the .zip file is not downloaded. I think, though, that the .zip file is transferred to the browser in its binary form through the response object passed to the function called on success.

3: scanning the jQuery webpage for events to listen to, but I only found on the triggering of the action (`$('#form').submit(...)`), not the response thereof.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery get and post methods?
You can listen to done, fail and always events.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

When you send the request you show your popup, and on always method you can just simply remove it.

Comment: @Botond, that is exactly what I have tried, see 2), but the response is "caught" by the success function call and not propagated to the browser (i guess).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Eureka!

I changed `return false` to `return true` in the `$.post` and now it works!

```
var $form = $('#extract_form');
$form.submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        $.unblockUI();
    }, 'text');
    return true;
});
```