# nodejs response to ajax is not printing on the same page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a beginner to nodejs and I am trying to send response from nodejs to ajax on client side. Everything is working fine, but the problem is as the response is received on clent side, a new page openes and the response is shown on that page. It means that the core functionality of ajax is not fulfilled. I want the ajax response to be displayed on the same page. Please help!!
Below is my server code:

```
    app.post('/auth',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;
    var obj={};
    if(username&&password){
        connection.query('select * from signup where username=? and password=?',[username,password],function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result!=0)
            {
                req.session.loggedin=true;
                req.session.username=username;
                return res.redirect('/home');
            }
            obj={'message':'Incorrect Username and/or Password'};
            obj=JSON.stringify(obj);
            res.send(obj);

        });
    }
});
```

This is my client side code. I want the response to be displayed inside the label with id "wrongdetail" but it is being printed on another page.
Below is my jquery ajax call:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){    
                $('#submitbut').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth',      
                        success: function(response) {
                          $('#wrongdetail').html("<b>"+response.message+"</b>");
                        }
                    });
                });    
            });
        </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login page</title>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="login-form">
  <h3>Sign In</h3>
  <form action="auth" method="post" class="form-content">
    <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username ..." id="usernm" required>
    <label for="password"><b>Enter Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password ..." id="passwd" required>
    <label for="wrong" id="wrongdetail"></label>
    <button id="submitbut">Login</button>
  </form> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form and stay on same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733808/submit-form-and-stay-on-same-page)

Comment: @DanO I tried the solution you mentioned, but the problem persists. It is not even submitting form data(no post request is made to the server). I tried the exact same thing in another code and it worked. See https://github.com/tyagivipul629/emp_detail . It is working fine

Comment: I think there is something to add on the server side. There is no problem in the ajax call